# Como recuperar dados usando FirebaseRecyclerAdapter que possui IDs gerados automaticamente?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, id, firebase-database

estou com um erro usando FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, na hora de recuperar os dados do firebase apresenta esse erro: "**com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap**"

Vi que é algo relacionado a leitura do ID criado para cada clínica, estou gerando uma chave automaticamente para cada clínica. Alguém pode me ajudar com isso? Como recupero as ids e mostro todas as clínicas cadastradas no firebase?

[image: Banco de dados no Firebase]

```
   mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    rootReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("clinicas");

    listaClinicas = new ArrayList<>();

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Clinicas, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Clinicas, ViewHolder>(
                    Clinicas.class,
                    R.layout.adapter_lista_clinicas,
                    ViewHolder.class,
                    rootReference

            ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final Clinicas clinicas, int position) {

                    final String clinicasIds = getRef(position).getKey();

                    rootReference.child(clinicasIds).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), clinicas.getNomeClinica(), clinicas.getEnderecoClinica(),
                                    clinicas.getBairroClinica(), clinicas.getEstadoCidadeClinica(), clinicas.getTelefoneClinica(), clinicas.getWhatsappClinica(),
                                    clinicas.getFoto2());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }
            };


    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sou novato em Firebase, mas acho que é porque você precisa criar um addListenerForSingleValueEvent para poder recuperar essas informações. Como no meu exemplo abaixo:

```
private void getUsuarioTecnicoId() {

    DatabaseReference tecnicoDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child("Clientes").child(usuarioAtualID).child("conexoes").child("tecnicos");
    tecnicoDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot tecnico: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    FetchtecnicoInformation(tecnico.getKey());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

private void FetchtecnicoInformation(final String key) {
    DatabaseReference usuarioDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child("Tecnicos").child(key);
    usuarioDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String usuarioId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                String nome = "";
                String profissao = "";
                String imagemPerfilUrl = "";

                if (dataSnapshot.child("nome").getValue()!=null){
                    nome = dataSnapshot.child("nome").getValue().toString();
                }

                if (dataSnapshot.child("profissao").getValue()!=null){
                    profissao = dataSnapshot.child("profissao").getValue().toString();
                }

                if (dataSnapshot.child("imagemPerfilUrl").getValue()!=null){
                    imagemPerfilUrl = dataSnapshot.child("imagemPerfilUrl").getValue().toString();
                }


                TecnicosObject obj = new TecnicosObject(usuarioId, nome, profissao, imagemPerfilUrl);
                resultmTecnicos.add(obj);
                mTecnicosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Mas como está o seu database? No meu caso estou usando o FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, não entendo onde e como devo recuperar e setar o id para que consigam ser localizado os dados.

Comment: Meu database eu pego por essa linha "    DatabaseReference tecnicoDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child("Clientes").child(usuarioAtualID).child("conexoes").child("tecnicos");
" Mas como não usei  esse FireBaseRecyclerAdapter pode ser diferente a abordagem.

Comment: Onde está declarado e como você recebe o dado da variável "usuarioAtualID"? Minha referencia está na raiz, mas ai tenho IDs, ai que dá o problema, não consigo achar uma forma de fazer minha referência chegar até ele e ler todos filhos do id gerado automaticamente com push.

Comment: private String usuarioAtualID; 

Dentro do OnCreate: usuarioAtualID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

O getCurrentUser().getUid(); pegará o ID do usuário atual logado.

Comment: Entendi, é porque no caso você está recebendo o id do usuário logado no app, no meu caso precisava chegar até os ids, meu recyclerview não mostra nada.

Comment: O que meu código faz é:

Primeiro crio uma referência para o banco de dados: 

DatabaseReference tecnicoDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child("Clientes").child(usuarioAtualID).child("conexoes").child("tecnicos");

Comment: Então crio um addListenerForSingleValueEvent para percorrer todos que estão no campo que busquei na referência:

for (DataSnapshot tecnico: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        FetchtecnicoInformation(tecnico.getKey());
                    }
O método FetchtecnicoInformation vai receber todos os id's e então eu percorro mais  uma vez o campo dos Tecnicos do banco de dados para dessa vez exibir no meu RecyclerView.